# stub request library in javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, request, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using a third party restful service for sending SMS verification code. I wrote an unit test for it. However I dont want to be sent a message each time I run the unit-test.

The code is like:

```
  const _request = require("request");

  _request({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://blah.com/json",
  form: {
    apikey: "blah",
    mobile: input.mobilePhoneNumber,
    text: `code is: ${verificationCode}`,
  }
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    dbg(`end, output=${err}`)
    return reject(new Error("something wrong"))
  } else {
    dbg(`end, output=${res}`)
    return resolve({})
  }
})
```

And in the test Im using sinon.stub

```
sinon.stub(request, "post").returns(Promise.resolve({}))
```

However this stub doesnt really catch the "post" method in request. I looked into the source code and tried many ways (like stub the constructor instead), but none works.

Wondering if there's anyone tried this before. How shall I stub this post method on request?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `request` in your unit test?

Comment: it's this lib: https://github.com/request/request @robertklep

Comment: Reason I was asking is because your code is not calling `request.post()` (it's calling `request`) and the `request` library itself doesn't support promises (so returning a promise from it from a stub doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not calling `request.post()`, so stubbing it won't catch the call you're making.

Instead, you need to stub the `request` function itself, which is difficult to do with Sinon alone because it requires a "parent" object in which it can replace/stub a method/function.

You can work around that using [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), which you can use to "catch" the import of `request` and replace it with a stub:

```
const sinon      = require('sinon');
const request    = require('request');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

let stub  = sinon.stub();
const mod = proxyquire('./your-module', { request : stub });
```

In your test cases, you can make `stub` yield to the callback you pass:

```
let fakeError    = null;
let fakeResponse = {};
let fakeBody     = '';

stub.reset();
stub.yields(fakeError, fakeResponse, fakeBody);
```

The arguments to `yields` represent `err`, `res` and `body` in your code. You can pass various combinations to check if your code handles the responses properly.

The reason for calling `stub.reset()` is that you need to make sure, before each test, that the stub is reset to its original state (so it starts "fresh").